# spring boot application not working bean error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, tomcat

I am new to Spring Boot and I'm getting the following error when writing a login validationAPI:

Field userservice in com.Productwebsite.controller.UserController required a bean of type 'com.Productwebsite.service.UserService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Controller class:

```java
package com.Productwebsite.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.Productwebsite.service.UserService;

@RestController
public class UserController {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserService userservice;
    
    @GetMapping("user/{username}/{password}")
    public int UserLogin(@PathVariable("username")String username1, @PathVariable("password")String password1) {
        int flag = userservice.loginValidation(username1, password1);
        if (flag == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        return flag;
    }
}
```

Modelclass:

```java
package com.Productwebsite.model;

public class users {
    String username;
    String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "users [username=" + username + ", password=" + password + "]";
    }

    public users(String username, String password) {
        super();
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public users() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

Service interfface:

```java
package com.Productwebsite.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserService {
    
    public int loginValidation(String username,String password);
}
```

Serviceimplementation class:

```java
package com.Productwebsite.serviceImp;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.Productwebsite.Dbutil.dbutil;
import com.Productwebsite.service.UserService;

@Service
public class ServiceImp implements UserService {
    Connection connection;
    int flag = 0;

    public ServiceImp() throws SQLException {
        connection = dbutil.getConnection();
    }

    @Override
    public int loginValidation(String username, String password) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement statement 
 = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='"+username+"'"); 
            ResultSet rs=statement.executeQuery();
            
            while(rs.next()) {
                if (rs.getString(1).equals(username)&&rs.getString(2).equals(password)) {
                    flag=1;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid username/password");
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return flag;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `@ComponentScan` to `com.Productwebsite` and restart the app.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.Productwebsite")
@SpringBootApplication
public class YourMainClass{
  ...
}
```

---

Try the following, if the above changes do not work:

Change annotation by adding the bean name:

```
@Repository("userservice")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help its works now .(after adding componentscan)
If you dont mind can u explain what happened

Comment: Sure. By default @springbootapplication annotation will take care of component scan based on the package it belongs to. in your case package might be somewhere  else.  Usually the main class would be in base package folder. In your case, the scan not happened and bean not created

Comment: @SureshKumar - you should add your comment to the answer.